# New relic couldn't find any database operations when using NestJS TypeORM and MySQL

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm, newrelic, node-mysql2

I connected newrelic APM Agent for and I see all operations and logs except for mysql. On newrelic APM > app > Databases i see `We couldn't find any Database operations.` On Distibuted tracing I see `Uninstrumented time` on each DB operation.
How can I set up newrelic to see DB operations using NestJS, TypeORM and MySQL?

Comment: What’s your actual question? See [ask]

Comment: @esqew sorry for not clear question. How can I set up newrelic to see DB operations using NestJS, TypeORM and MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

I see a mention of `appNames`, so I am assuming you are referring to APM data ingest.

The steps to get there is:

- Data Management Hub
- Click on APM Events in legend -> Click on the area for APM (Or
  directly click on APM area in the chart)
- Pick the query from the modal (Usually looks something like below)

```
SELECT bytecountestimate()/10e8 FROM `Transaction`, `TransactionError` FACET appName LIMIT 15 SINCE 1684442429581 UNTIL 1684528829581
```

- Note that the modal only shows Top 15 results for last 24 hours. But
  the query from the modal can be modified to show data ingest details
  for longer time window too by updating the `SINCE` and `UNTIL` clauses to
  `SINCE 30 DAYS AGO UNTIL TODAY`